# Change TinyMCE background by jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, tinymce

I have a form with a colorpicker and a TinyMCE editor. The user can choose a new background color for the TinyMCE. If the user has chosen a color, the editor gets right away the new background.

This is my code:

```
$(".color-picker").miniColors({
        letterCase: 'uppercase',
        change: function(hex) {
            $("iframe > html").css("background-color", hex);
            $("iframe > body").css("background-color", hex);
        }
    });
```

But nothing is changing..

How can I change the background color of the TinyMCE editor with jQuery?

Plz

Answer (score 1):

kpotehin was close, but using his code will modify all iframes on your page and not just the editor iframe you want to change the background to. Using the active tinymce editor and some editor relevant functions, the solution to your problem is

```
$(".color-picker").miniColors({
      letterCase: 'uppercase',
      change: function(hex) {
          $(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody()).css("background-color",'#' + hex);
          $(tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().parentNode).css("background-color",'#' + hex);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be better to post html code too.
But it seems to me that you just have to add '#' before hex.
Your example:

```
$(".color-picker").miniColors({
        letterCase: 'uppercase',
        change: function(hex) {
            $("iframe > html").css("background-color",'#' + hex);
            $("iframe > body").css("background-color",'#' + hex);
        }
    });
```

Comment: close, but your code will change the background of all iframes on the page instead of just the editor iframe